# loading an external pdf document into div

Tags: php, jquery

what would you recommend to be the most effective way to load a pdf document into a div?

taking into consideration the size of the div (the pdf must scale to fit the div) and how the multiple pages in the pdf would be displayed.

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<div>
<object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>
</div>
```