# Most elegant way to print differing file formats stored as BLOBs

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have a table with checkboxes that corresponds to BLOBs kept in MySQL database. These are all different types of files txt, xls, doc, pdf, etc. I am new to programming so I am not sure how to best allow my users to print these files in groups? I understand I cant control their hardware so I need to display these files in a window where they print the contents correct?

Should I somehow figure out how to display all the selected files in one pop up window or is that even possible? (eg user selects a .pdf and .doc file, do I try to get those two to display together and the user can print contents of that window? Maybe loop through and put them in divs something like suggested here? [loading an external pdf document into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138632/loading-an-external-pdf-document-into-div))

Or do I have to display each file in its own window and the user just selects print from that window? The user is going to think of the combined documents as one big package so the last suggestion is by far the least elegant. I guess I could just display each file in a separate tab so they can print, that is how it is setup now but I would like to display the files for print all together if at all possible. How has the community handled this in the past? Any advice for a beginner is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that for the purpose of keeping things less confusing for an end user, you'd want them to open in separate windows.

Your user will need some type of plugin in order to properly display a .pdf file however. As far as .doc, .xls, etc. files, you'll have to convert the file to a .html file so that it has some/most of the formatting, otherwise the users browser will ask them to open a local program to read the .doc file.

One option that would probably be the easier solutions, is have the server take the selections, convert the items to pdf files and then merge all of the pdf files. This would keep them sequential like you asked...all in the browser...and you could give the user the option to save the pdf file on their local machine if they want to.

Comment: I had no idea this would be so difficult but with different formats I'm getting an idea as to why. You suggested opening different windows...I'm concerned if there are 10 documents opening 10 tabs at once will crash their browser. Do you see a problem with this? How difficult would it be to convert doc, xls, jpegs etc to a single pdf? I'm just wondering if its worth it to even look into it or do you suggest sticking with the multiple windows scenario? If so is there a more elegant way to handle that?

Comment: This is what I recommend reading if you want to convert the files to a single pdf on a linux server. Hopefully this helps you.[link]http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/177241.html[/link]